# Only column text appears when csv file is imported to datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net

This is my first vb.net program, so please bear with me if my question is very mediocre.

Before mentioning my problem, the mechanism of my accounting program is that if the user would input data into the datagridview and export it, so that when he restarts the program, he can import the exported data.

I have imported this .csv file to my datagridview

[image]

The problem is that when I have imported it, only column texts would appear like this.

[image]

**This is the export code that I have used to create the .csv file.**

```
 Private Sub ExportToExcelToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExportToExcelToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim msg1 = "Export Successful"
    Dim title = "Excel Export"

    MsgBox(msg1, , title)
    Try
        Dim iexport1 As String = ""
        Dim eexport1 As String = ""
        For Each C As DataGridViewColumn In Income.Columns
            iexport1 &= """" & C.HeaderText & ""","
        Next
        iexport1 = iexport1.Substring(0, iexport1.Length - 1)
        iexport1 &= Environment.NewLine
        For Each R As DataGridViewRow In Income.Rows
            For Each C As DataGridViewCell In R.Cells
                If Not C.Value Is Nothing Then
                    iexport1 &= """" & C.Value.ToString & ""","
                Else
                    iexport1 &= """" & "" & ""","
                End If
            Next
            iexport1 = iexport1.Substring(0, iexport1.Length - 1)
            iexport1 &= Environment.NewLine
        Next

        For Each C As DataGridViewColumn In Expense.Columns
            eexport1 &= """" & C.HeaderText & ""","
        Next
        eexport1 = eexport1.Substring(0, eexport1.Length - 1)
        eexport1 &= Environment.NewLine
        For Each R As DataGridViewRow In Expense.Rows
            For Each C As DataGridViewCell In R.Cells
                If Not C.Value Is Nothing Then
                    eexport1 &= """" & C.Value.ToString & ""","
                Else
                    eexport1 &= """" & "" & ""","
                End If
            Next
            eexport1 = eexport1.Substring(0, eexport1.Length - 1)
            eexport1 &= Environment.NewLine
        Next

        Dim tw As IO.TextWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(path:="C:\Users\S2009516\Desktop\JanuaryIncome.CSV")
        tw.Write(iexport1)
        tw.Close()
        Dim tw2 As IO.TextWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(path:="C:\Users\S2009516\Desktop\JanuaryExpense.CSV")
        tw2.Write(eexport1)
        tw2.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

**And this is the one I have used for importing csv file.**

```
Private Sub ImportFromExcelToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ImportFromExcelToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim expenseload1 As String = "C:\Users\S2009516\Desktop\JanuaryExpense.CSV"
    Dim incomeload1 As String = "C:\Users\S2009516\Desktop\JanuaryIncome.CSV"

    Try
        Dim expensereader1 As New StreamReader(expenseload1, Encoding.Default)
        Dim incomereader1 As New StreamReader(incomeload1, Encoding.Default)
        Dim eline As String = ""
        Dim iline As String = ""
        Do
            eline = expensereader1.ReadLine
            iline = incomereader1.ReadLine
            If eline Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If iline Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Dim words() As String = eline.Split(",")
            Dim words2() As String = iline.Split(",")
            Income.Rows.Add("")
            Expense.Rows.Add("")
            For ix As Integer = 0 To 3
                Me.Income.Rows(Income.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(ix).Value = words2(ix)
                Me.Expense.Rows(Income.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(ix).Value = words(ix)
            Next
        Loop
        expensereader1.Close()
        incomereader1.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

I have no clue on why this is happening... I have followed all the steps in the tutorial video.. Please save my soul... I have been stuck with this for 2 days already.

Comment: Learn to debug.. Do you know how to set a breakpoint? Click on the left border of one line in the code and a red circle will appear.. Then, when you run the program it will stop at that line. At this point you can control the execution line by line and inspect values from variables... either hover over variable or right click and "Add watch"... Debug - Step over (F10) to go to the next line.. you will see exactly what's going on. Hope it helps..

Comment: I am so sorry but your suggestion does not help me at all. I don't understand what that says... I have also tried other tutorial videos about importing csv file to datagridview but it seems like they do not solve my problem.

Comment: @jason does you csv file actually contains the missing lines?

Comment: I have figured the way out thanks to tutorial youtubers. I did the openfiledialog one. Still don't know why the one i have posted didn't work though.